# Whats the best way to update Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, upgrade

I have a Ubuntu 9.04 server which has no packase support anymore. If I want to update my package lists, I get th following errors:

```
 Err http://de.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/multiverse Packages
   404 Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
 W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
 ....
```

I read at the official [Ubuntu-Support-Page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/upgrade), that there is a `update-manager-core`-Package to upgrade to a new release. Unfortunately I dont have this package installed and I am unable to install it because of the lack of package sources.

**EDIT:** Installing the package `update-manager-core` from another release doesn't work because it depends on a higher version of `python-apt`. (Tried with 10.04)

```
 $ dpkg -i update-manager-core_0.134.7_amd64.deb
 Selecting previously deselected package update-manager-core.
 (Reading database ... 28743 files and directories currently installed.)
 Unpacking update-manager-core (from update-manager-core_0.134.7_amd64.deb) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager-core:
  update-manager-core depends on python-apt (>= 0.7.13.4ubuntu3); however:
   Version of python-apt on system is 0.7.9~exp2ubuntu10.
  update-manager-core depends on python-gnupginterface; however:
   Package python-gnupginterface is not installed.
 dpkg: error processing update-manager-core (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  update-manager-core
```

So, whats the best way to upgrade to to current Release without reinstalling the complete (virtual) server?

Comment: what if you get the update-manager-core deb file from another version (for example from 10.04)? url: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/update-manager-core

Comment: Does `do-release-upgrade` depend on the package lists, too?

Comment: I've tried it, but it depends on a higher version of python (see my edit)

Comment: This thread saved my ass today. And since I don't have enough reputation to upvote, I'd like to say thank you here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself.

Download the ISO-File and mount it in a local folder:

```
 wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/jaunty/ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64.iso 
 mkdir cdrom
 mount -o loop ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64.iso
```

Adjust the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the local folder

```
 deb file:///tmp/cdrom/ main
```

Perform an update and install `update-manager-core`

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Now a System update from 9.04 to 9.10 and then from 9.10 to 10.04 LTS works fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you are useing virtulization that /dev/loop# might be unpremited to use (security reasons), however the DEB file is still on the jaunty cd so if you can mount it locally you can upload it to your server and run dpkg -i update_manager_whatever.deb for the same result.

The file is in pool/u/update-manager

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue starting at 9.10. Thanks greatly to Fu86. I had to make some slight modifications due to errors I encountered, but the information provided was very helpful.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/karmic/ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.iso
mkdir cdrom
```

Mounting the image using Fu86's method gave me

```
mount: can't find ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.iso in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

However this worked as desired:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 ubuntu-9.10-server-amd64.iso /tmp/cdrom
```

Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file adding the directory on the mounted iso. I had to do this a little differently so as not to get an error about a "Malformed [...] dist parse". In the following command `karmic` is the directory inside the `dists` directory within `cdrom` and `main` is the directory within that:

```
deb file:///tmp/cdrom/ karmic main
```

Finally I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Good luck and thanks again to Fu86 for most of this info.